# How to make my spring boot application online on my domain?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, war, web-hosting

I have recently learned how to work with `Spring boot`. Now, I have an application which works locally without any problem. Now, I would like to know how I can make it available as a website.
I have got a free web host from [here](https://www.000webhost.com/) and have followed the instructions to create a `war` file for my project. But I don't know what I should do with this `war` file and how I should use it to have my web page online.
In the meantime, my code is using `Atlas Mongodb` in it. Is using a `database` problematic? Should I consider something special for that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should explore how java web applications are deployed. Attached link leads to common hosting not supporting java. Your war file should be added to a running servlet container (e.g. Apache Tomcat). You can rent VM and install that container on it. Alternatively, you can use any cloud platform, e.g. Heroku with its free plan

Comment: if you had thought about  that at first you probably  would choose laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared hosting like 000webhost do not support Spring boot Hosting. As it was said earlier to host spring boot you have two choices either you host jar or war file. War is the traditional way of hosting it which needs Apache tomcat server and Jar is the Modern way which supports cloud based solutions. To host your solution you can create an account with AWS(Amazon web services) or GCP (Google Cloud Platform) and you will get free credits to use for a while or you can use Heroku(https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku) which is pretty much easier to use, its free also. For the database if you are using (https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) then you are good. All the best

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The only point which is still unclear to me is how I can get my own domain. I mean, when I deploy my code on heroku, I can get it to work on myapp.heroku.com, how can I get it online on myapp.com? Could you please help me in that regard?

Comment: I have never tried that, so may be you should search online if it is possible you will easily see that, Goodluck

Comment: You can buy a domain from www.domains.google or domains.com, among many others. There are reviews of all of the options from PCMag and TechRadar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, which have an embedded tomcat. You can just pack your project to a jar file, put the jar file to the server, and then simply execute it on the network interface that can connect to the outside world.

If you would like to pack your project as a war file, then you should first install the environment (application server) like tomcat, glassfish, jboss, etc. After that, you can deploy the war file on the application server.

Likewise, you should install the database server on your host, and edit the spring application.properties to let your spring application connect to the database.